# XPATH on HTML in Metro App

Tags: html, xpath, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

is there any Library out there which gives `XPATH` over `HTML`?

There are lots of famous `HTML` parsers available for .Net framework but non of them supports `WinRT` or `XPath`!

Comment: Have you tried Selenium or Html Agility Pack?

Comment: Yeah, It seems that Selenium does not supprt WinRT and HAP does not support XPATH in its WinRT version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the System.XML or the System.XML.Linq over the HTML document which has parse engines against Documents, Nodes,Elements etc..

You can also try the HTML Agility Pack for Metro, published at this link: https://bitbucket.org/antiufo/htmlagilitypack-for-metro/